# Embed Google map as foreignObject in svg

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to ultimately embed a map from a provider, Google in the first instance, inside an SVG as a foreignObject using a script to generate the innerHTML.

This works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<svg xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="150" fill="gray"/>
  <foreignObject x="10" y="10" width="100" height="150">
<body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <div id="mapholder"></div>
  <script>
    var inner = "sdkjfh";
    document.getElementById("mapholder").innerHTML = inner;
  </script>
</body>
</foreignObject>
</svg>
```

and displays a grey rectangle with the string "sdkjfh" in it

but if I change inner to be 
`var inner = "<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x300"/>";`

I get just the empty grey rectangle and inspecting the DOM shows that the innerHTML of mapholder hasn't been set to the img but it is clearing the contents if I had already had it set to something.

Finally if I set the div to contain the img tag statically and forgo javascript altogether then it displays the map but prevents me from being dynamic as I would need.

Can anyone suggest why the difference in behavior when using a script in the foreignObject to set anything other than a simple string?

Comment: How are you displaying the SVG itself?

Comment: For now I'm just loading it in Chrome

Comment: As a file? I don't think Chrome's security policy allows files make http requests. You probably need to load it via a web server to get it working.

Comment: No I checked and it makes no difference if I do it as a file or host it on a web server and load it from there.  Even if I change inner to insert <p>text</p> it shows nothing.